# if statement not executing inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Not sure why the if statement inside the second for loop not executing, anyone who can point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change;
  var balance = [];
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i<cid.length; i++) {
    total += cid[i][1];
    change = cash - price;  
    if (total < change) {
      return "Insufficient Funds";
    } else if (total === change) {
      return "Closed";
    } 
  }
  for (var x = 8; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (change > cid[x][1] && change <= cid[x][1]) {
      balance.push(cid[x-1][1]);
    }
  }
  return balance;
} //end function

checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME",     3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

Comment: The condition just doesn't make sense. The value can't be bigger and at the same time smaller/equals.

Comment: ...unless `cid[x]` has a getter which returns a different value each time the `"1"` property is read. Not probable.

Comment: `change > cid[x][1] && change <= cid[x][1]` doesn't make sense.. ? Aren't you thinking about `change > cid[x][1] && change <= cid[x-1][1]` or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the logic of the if statement: `change > cid[x][1] && change <= cid[x][1]`

You're saying that if `change` is greater than `cid[x][1]` AND `change` is less than or equal to `cid[x][1]`. That logic will never execute because one number can never be both larger AND smaller than or equal to another's number at the same time.

Let `change = 5` and `cid[x][1] = 0.25`, plugging those value into the logic you'll see that it's not possible for 5 to be larger AND smaller than or equal to 0.25 at the same time. (`5 > 0.25 && 5 <= 0.25`).

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is trying to check if `change` is greater than `cid[x][1]` AND if `change` is less than/equal to `cid[x][1]`.

This will never be true.

`change` will always either be greater than `cid[x][1]` or less than/equal to it.